# List View more collides with page view more

Tags: lists, pagination

We are putting together a page with a list of Rules.
We limit the number of rules that can be seen by page to 48 and add a View More at the bottom of the page.

Each rule is expandable on the page and may have a list of locations associated to them. There can be 100 locations associated to one rule. So we also want to add a View more for the locations.

Challenge:
The last rule expanded on the page has 100 locations and shows 'View more', then immediately below it we can see the Rules View more at the bottom of the page. This is cluttered and not clear to the user of the page.

Thoughts on a cleaner design?

Comment: Some images can help understanding the problem better and might result in better answers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! We have decided to go to a subpage for the locations which should help. We already have search and sort functions, our business users also wanted to be able to see the full list.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to the site!

I try to weed out the "More" button in all designs I get to see. For me, the solution is a (single!) scrollbar and lazy loading.

Have you considered move the 100 locations to a dialog or subpage? One hundred sounds like everyone would want search and sort functions, and the single page (with more than 48 rules in total) will become crowded.

Comment: The trouble with doing away with the 'more' option is that if people are trying to get to the site footer they can't get to it as new content keeps loading in just as they scroll to the bottom. Personally, I think a single 'View More' option works well, and have it trigger the lazy-loading (so once you click that More button everything lazy-loads after that, but you need to click it initially to trigger that action so that we know the user does want to see more results).